# build query to select data based on another table

Tags: mysql

tables
[image]

sample data

walls

```
wall_id   wall_name
  1        wall_1
  2        wall_2
  6        wall_6
```

wall_categories

```
wall_id   category_id
  1           2
  2           1
  6           1
  6           2
```

categories

```
category_id  category_name
  1            Wallpaper
  2            Photography
```

html

```
<a href="file.php?category=wallpaper">Wallpaper</a>
<a href="file.php?category=photography">Photography</a>
```

What I need to do is when the user click the `Wallpaper` link, I want the images with `wallpaper` as category to be displayed same with `photography`. I have built an initial query but it generates duplicate records as I'm using join, there must be something else that need to be added to make it work.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT walls.wall_id, walls.wall_name, walls.wall_views, walls.upload_date,
 categories.category_name FROM categories INNER JOIN wall_categories ON 
wall_categories.category_id=categories.category_id INNER JOIN walls ON 
walls.wall_id=wall_categories.wall_id;
```

or since the `category_id` is fixed, we can use `walls` and `wall_categories` table only. Then lets' say we can use the following html.

```
<a href="file.php?category=1">Wallpaper</a>
<a href="file.php?category=2">Photography</a>
```

Comment: Are there hundreds of images? If not I'd just grab the whole dataset and handle the display issues at the application level.

Comment: not yet, but there will be in the near future.

Comment: I think you need a `WHERE categories.category_id = 1` OR `WHERE categories.category_id = 2` depending on which link user clicks on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not limiting your query by `category_id`, so it's returning all wall records that have an associated category.

```
SELECT DISTINCT walls.wall_id, walls.wall_name, walls.wall_views, walls.upload_date,
 categories.category_name FROM categories INNER JOIN wall_categories ON 
wall_categories.category_id=categories.category_id INNER JOIN walls ON 
walls.wall_id=wall_categories.wall_id
WHERE category.category_id = ?
;
```

And then bind `?` to the appropriate category ID from your user's selection.

Comment: Of course. Any set of conditions that evaluate to a boolean true will cause the row to be included. Please make sure you read up on SQL before you go too much further, that's a very basic question and you'll want to understand that before you get into the project much more.